# Chkdsk gives following output "NTFSNTFSNTFSNTFS"

Tags: windows-8.1, ntfs, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption

I have Windows 8.1 Pro N x64 and I got an error saying "This directory is corrupt" so I decided to run a chkdsk on my C: drive. I put in the Command prompt "chkdsk /f C:" but It gave me the output of "NTFSNTFSNTFSNTFS". I ran "where chkdsk" and I got C:\Windows\System32\chkdsk.exe. How do I fix this?

Comment: sound strange, can you provide a screenshot of how `It gave me the output of "NTFSNTFSNTFSNTFS".` looks like?

Comment: try running chkdsk without any switches.